# how can i allow user to scroll large text files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, infinite-scroll

I have very large text files that can reach 10's of gb's(on server side), and want the ability for user to scroll through them on my website.
This will allow them to view it without needing to download a program such as glogg.
I thought about implementing something that shows lines of text based on the users scroll positon, although i dont really know how to start doing this.
My website is build on react and nodejs.
Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at **react-infinite-scroll-component** and **react-scroll**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overflow` property in your css

Comment: from what i saw, overflow will give me the scrolling effect, but my main issue is that i cannot send all the text of the file from the server to the client because it is too large.

Comment: I guess you need to split your file to seperate files and then use `IntersectionObserver` so when the user scroll down, at certain point you need to add another text file that you seperated to your text. I dont know how can you implement it on react because i never implemented it before but it looks like this is the way you can achieve what you want.

This is a great question btw. Please let me know if you achieved it. And explain how did you make it.